# how to draw polyline google maps from mysql using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

I'm trying to insert polylines onto google maps using coordinates that are stored in a mysql table. I'm fairly new to php..

this is my code

```
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 12,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-7.275920,112.791871),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

var flightPlanCoordinates = [
<?php
include('koneksi.php');
$sql = mysql_select_db('test', $connection);

$query1 = mysql_query ("SELECT lat FROM user_location");
$query11 = mysql_query ("SELECT long1 FROM user_location");

$query2 = mysql_query ("SELECT lat name FROM route");
$query22 = mysql_query ("SELECT lng,name FROM route");

$query3 = mysql_query ("SELECT lat2 FROM user_location");
$query33 = mysql_query ("SELECT long2 FROM user_location");

$data1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1);
$data2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query11);
$data3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2);
$data4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query22);
$data5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query3);
$data6 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query33);
?>

var result1 = "<?php echo $data1; ?>";
var result2 = "<?php echo $data2; ?>";
var result3 = "<?php echo $data3; ?>";
var result4 = "<?php echo $data4; ?>";
var result5 = "<?php echo $data5; ?>";
var result6 = "<?php echo $data6; ?>";

new google.maps.LatLng(result1, result2),
new google.maps.LatLng(result3, result4),
new google.maps.LatLng(result5, result6)
];

var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: flightPlanCoordinates,
geodesic: true,
strokeColor: '#FF0000',
strokeOpacity: 1.0,
strokeWeight: 2
});
flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

when I run in myweb its no result. just only blank but no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, this is a tough one to figure out with your information provided so I tried my best. Also mysql was deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. You should be using mysqli. Although this will fix your problem, Id suggest looking at the way your database is structured and how you do your queries.

**Result:**
[image]

**Source Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Polylines</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
    function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-7.275920,112.791871),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

    var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    <?php
    //If konesi.php outputs ANYTHING, the map will fail to load. However, you should
    //change the connection variable to $connection = mysqli_connect("HOST","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DATABASE");
    include('koneksi.php');

    //switch to correct database
    mysqli_select_db($connection,"test");

    //Query the user for start and ending location. Store locations in variables
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT lat, long1, lat2, long2 FROM user_location LIMIT 1");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $lat = $row['lat'];
    $lon = $row['long1'];
    $lat2 = $row['lat2'];
    $lon2 = $row['long2'];

    //Echo out the users start location
    echo 'new google.maps.LatLng('.$lat.', '.$lon.'),';

    //Assuming route that lat and long coordinates are in multiple records and not in a array within a single record
    //Loop through all records and echo out the positions
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT lat, lng FROM route");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $lat = $row['lat'];
        $lon = $row['lng'];
        echo 'new google.maps.LatLng('.$lat.', '.$lon.'),';
    }

    //echo users ending position
    echo 'new google.maps.LatLng('.$lat2.', '.$lon2.')';

    ?>

    ];

    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });
    flightPath.setMap(map);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Coordinates used:**

```
    -7.322984, 112.716165 User Start
    -7.317110, 112.717109 Route Record
    -7.310725, 112.712560 Route Record
    -7.306511, 112.701102 Route Record
    -7.292974, 112.698012 Route Record
    -7.280586, 112.708140 Route Record
    -7.272754, 112.708612 User End
```

**SQL Dump:**

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `test`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `route`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `route` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`lat` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`lng` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `route`
--

INSERT INTO `route` (`id`, `name`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES
(5, '', '-7.317110', '112.717109'),
(6, '', '-7.310725', '112.712560'),
(7, '', '-7.306511', '112.701102'),
(8, '', '-7.292974', '112.698012'),
(9, '', '-7.280586', '112.708140');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `user_location`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_location` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`lat` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`long1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`lat2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`long2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `user_location`
--

INSERT INTO `user_location` (`id`, `lat`, `long1`, `lat2`, `long2`) VALUES
(1, '-7.322984', '112.716165', '-7.272754', '112.708612');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```